# How to create Admin form in Magento 2 without using Uicomponent?

Tags: admin, magento2.2, forms, uicomponent, edit-form

I have a grid which is showing data and know I want to create action and Add new Button. But I don't want to use Uicomponent.

Can someone tell me how to create a admin form step by step (Admin form CRUD without using Ui Component).

Comment: Can I ask what is your reason for not wanting to use it? I've got XML fatigue and I'm always curious for learning new approaches

Comment: I'm trying to do that because I am using api content to fill a grid and I need a form to search registers using that api. So, I am using data from api not from database. Ui componentes are helpful only with database stuff... In my case I will need to do anything using blocks.